# How to apply a method to an entire object literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you apply a method to all properties of an object literal?

For Example:

```
var ObjL = {
    x: $("someSelector > .x"),
    y: $("someSelector > .y"),
    otherx: $("someOtherSelector > .x"),
    othery: $("someOtherSelector > .y"),
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
// <---something like ObjL.css("background-color","red") would go here
```

Would you just use `ObjL.someMethod()`?

Could you do this with an array?

Comment: Google "_javascript iterate object properties_"...

Comment: it's a bit tricky when you search there. many answers will lead you to just use a plain for loop. there are answers here regarding good practices when prop-looping.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli: Nothing wrong with plain `for-in` loop.

Comment: hmmm actually u're right, since the object in the OP question is a literal one. but you've to be careful when the object has a prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to apply a `method` `aMethod` to an element? The best solution IMHO is a foreach loop:

```
$.each($obj, function(prop, value) {
    //call a method here, being the same on value or this.
    value.css(blablabla, blablabla);
});
```

(deliberately i did not use the `for` loop since 1. u're using jquery and it's shorter, and 2. it has many problems regarding the owned or inherited-by-proto properties).

**EDIT**: yes, you can use a $.each loop as well for arrays. an alternative is using a regular for-counter loop (for(initial;condition;increment){ code }), since using for(in) loops in arrays lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
$.each(ObjL, function() {
    this.css("background-color","red");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the object:

```
for (var key in ObjL) {
  if (ObjL.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    ObjL[key].css( /* do your thang */ );
  }
}
```